# Amplify - "Invalid username and password" in iOS

Tags: ios, aws-amplify

I'm working on an app on iOS and I'm using AWS Amplify for the authentication process. A new user account has been created successfully from the app. But I am not able to log in with the same account, I always get this response:

> notAuthorized(message: "Incorrect username or password.")

All the users are CONFIRMED in Cognito.

Comment: Hey did you find something on this

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1181#issuecomment-491831902) solved the issue for me.

In essence, my user pool ID had changed. I was still able to create users but logging in did not work which was throwing me off.